# Compare strings (token lists), comes before, comes after

Tags: latex3

How to compare two strings (token lists)? I'd like to know if `2021-05-16` comes before `2021-06-01` or not. We can assume that the two strings have the same length. I found the macros `\tl_if_eq`, `\str_if_eq` and `\int_compare`, but no real "comes before" string comparison like (the hypothetical) `\tl_if_lt` or `\tl_compare`.

Comment: the next l3kernel version will have a `\str_compare:nNnTF`, see https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/927

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're sure that your argument expand to proper ISO dates, you can do as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\isisodatebeforeTF}{mmmm}
 {
  \mhchem_isisodatebefore:eeTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \mhchem_isisodatebefore:nn { p, T, F, TF }
 {
  \int_compare:nTF
   {
    \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { 1 } { 4 }
    \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { 6 } { 7 }
    \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { 9 } { 10 }
    >
    \tl_range:nnn { #2 } { 1 } { 4 }
    \tl_range:nnn { #2 } { 6 } { 7 }
    \tl_range:nnn { #2 } { 9 } { 10 }
   }
   { \prg_return_true: } { \prg_return_false: }
 }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \mhchem_isisodatebefore:nn { ee } { p, T, F, TF }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\isisodatebeforeTF{2021-05-16}{2021-06-01}{Yes}{No}

\isisodatebeforeTF{2021-06-01}{2021-05-16}{Yes}{No}

\isisodatebeforeTF{2021-05-16}{2021-05-16}{Yes}{No}

\def\dateA{2021-05-16} \def\dateB{2021-06-01}

\isisodatebeforeTF{\dateA}{\dateB}{Yes}{No}

\isisodatebeforeTF{\dateB}{\dateA}{Yes}{No}

\isisodatebeforeTF{\dateA}{\dateA}{Yes}{No}

\end{document}
```

[image]